# Is Siddhi unable to group by more than one variable?

Tags: java, wso2, siddhi

I have the following stream definition:

`String eventStreamDefinition = 
            "define stream cdrEventStream (nodeId string, phone string, timeStamp long, isOutgoingCall bool); ";`

And the query:

`String query = "@info(name = 'query1') from cdrEventStream#window.externalTime(timeStamp,5 sec) select nodeId, phone, timeStamp, isOutgoingCall, count(nodeId) as callCount group by phone,isOutgoingCall insert all events into outputStream;";`

But when I try to compile them I get:

```
org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.exception.SiddhiParserException: You have an error in your SiddhiQL at line 1:267, extraneous input ',' expecting {'#', STREAM, DEFINE, TABLE, FROM, PARTITION, WINDOW, SELECT, GROUP, BY, HAVING, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, RETURN, EVENTS, INTO, OUTPUT, EXPIRED, CURRENT, SNAPSHOT, FOR, RAW, OF, AS, OR, AND, ON, IS, NOT, WITHIN, WITH, BEGIN, END, NULL, EVERY, LAST, ALL, FIRST, JOIN, INNER, OUTER, RIGHT, LEFT, FULL, UNIDIRECTIONAL, YEARS, MONTHS, WEEKS, DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES, SECONDS, MILLISECONDS, FALSE, TRUE, STRING, INT, LONG, FLOAT, DOUBLE, BOOL, OBJECT, ID_QUOTES, ID}
    at org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.internal.SiddhiErrorListener.syntaxError(SiddhiErrorListener.java:34)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:65)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:558)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportUnwantedToken(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:377)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.sync(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:275)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.SiddhiQLParser.group_by(SiddhiQLParser.java:3783)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.SiddhiQLParser.query_section(SiddhiQLParser.java:3713)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.SiddhiQLParser.query(SiddhiQLParser.java:1903)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.SiddhiQLParser.execution_element(SiddhiQLParser.java:619)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.SiddhiQLParser.execution_plan(SiddhiQLParser.java:550)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.SiddhiQLParser.parse(SiddhiQLParser.java:152)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.SiddhiCompiler.parse(SiddhiCompiler.java:61)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:59)
```

The only way I can get the query to compile is by removing `isOutgoingCall` from the `group by` clause. The Siddhi docs states that grouping by more than one variable should be possible. Is this a bug?

This is on version 3.0.0-alpha.

Comment: `group by` _after_ `insert ... into outputStream`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Anyway, solved it by upgrading to 3.0.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by several variables is supported by Siddhi 3.0.0. I just checked your query with Siddhi 3.0.0 and I was able to compile it. But of course I used released 3.0.0. Can you please give it a try.

Tip: You can use [Siddhi try it](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Siddhi+Try+It+Tool) to easily try out your queries